# Enabling .htaccess files via puppet

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vagrant, puppet

I'm trying to enable .htaccess files in Apache using Vagrant and Puppet.  When I add the "override" parameter to my vhost config and run "vagrant up", I get an error:

> Invalid parameter override in [...]

When I remove that line, the vm boots perfectly and runs.  Except, .htaccess files are ignored.

Here's my vhost config:

```
apache::vhost { 'local.testsite':
  server_name   => 'local.testsite',
  serveraliases => [],
  docroot       => '/var/www/',
  port          => '80',
  env_variables => [],
  priority      => '1',
  override   => ["All"],
}
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like your module doesn't expect the 'override' parameter. Which apache module are you using?

Comment: @GerApeldoorn I don't know how to find that out, but the first mention of apache in my default.pp file looks like this:

`class { 'apache': }

apache::dotconf { 'custom':
  content => 'EnableSendfile Off',
}
`

Comment: As @GerApeldoorn mentioned, your apache::vhost define(?) does not provide an 'override' parameter. Edit your question to include the contents of your apache::vhost define and we'll have better luck helping you out. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the latest version of the puppetlabs-apache module
I see an *allow_override* attribute and not *override*

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache#allow_override